# ReactiveCocoa: Correct use of signals for checking entity availability

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to write a reactive solution for the following scenario.

Tapping on a button, if there are some entities available in the database the user must be pushed to new view controller, otherwise an attempt to download these entities should be done and the check performed again.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
// VIEW CONTROLLER
self.button.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
        return self.viewModel.rac_checkEntitiesAvailability;
    }];

[self.button.rac_command.executionSignals.flatten subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    if([x boolValue] == YES) {
        // Entities available, can perform segue
    } else {
        // Error
}];

// VIEW-MODEL
- (RACSignal*)rac_checkEntitiesAvailability {
    return [[RACSignal return:@([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 0)]
            flattenMap:^RACStream *(id entitiesAvailable) {
                if([entitiesAvailable boolValue]) {
                    return [RACSignal return:@YES];
                } else {
                    return [[[self rac_downloadEntities] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
                        // This takes into account network problems too
                        return [RACSignal return:@([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 0)];
                    }];
                }
            }];
}
```

It seems to work but as I'm new to the ReactiveCocoa world I'm not sure it's really correct or could be written in less redundant way.

Many thanks,
DAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would honestly advise against direct binding of control events when UIControls are involved. If you use a RACCommand (declared and created in your viewModel) you can easily bind your UI to the state of the download (executing signal), show alert messages upon failures and presenting new UI upon success (if needed).
Your revised version of the code seems good to me, but I would probably simplify your inner signal: you don't need to wrap a boolean "immediate" variable around a return signal (=you don't need a signal to know how many entities you have in your CoreData model, it's a synchronous operation).
Something like this (check syntax, it may be wrong with all those square brackets)

```
[RACSignal defer:^RACSignal *{
    if([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 0) {
        return [RACSignal return:@YES];
    } else {
        return [[self rac_downloadEntities] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
            // This takes into account network problems too
            return [RACSignal return:@([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 0)];
    }];
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to create a signal for button events. MVVM is used for observing data changes and changing UI automatically. You can write codes like this:

```
button.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    if (xxx) {
        // Entities available, can perform segue
    } else {
        // Error
    }
    return [RACSignal empty];
}];
```

Or you can handle events directly:

```
[[button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    if (xxx) {
        // Entities available, can perform segue
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}];
```

Don't try to resolve all problems via RAC.

===========

For your scenario, you should use block. Add a download function like this:

```
@interface Entity ()

+ (int)MR_countOfEntities;
+ (void)MR_downloadEntites:(void(^)(void))finishBlock;

@end

@implementation Entity

static int _MR_countOfEntities = 0;
+ (int)MR_countOfEntities
{
    return _MR_countOfEntities;
}

+ (void)MR_downloadEntites:(void (^)(void))finishBlock
{
    // Download entites. This is an example.
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:@"http://test.com/entites" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        _MR_countOfEntities = 1;
        finishBlock();
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        _MR_countOfEntities = 0;
        finishBlock();
    }];
}

@end
```

So you can modify the codes of button like this:

```
[[button rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    if ([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 1) {
        // Entities available, can perform segue
    } else {
        [Entity MR_downloadEntites:^{
            if ([Entity MR_countOfEntities] > 1) {
                // Entities available, can perform segue
            } else {
                // Error
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi Harrison, it's not clear to me what you'd write in the command block with this solution. Could you complete your example using my code? Thanks

Comment: @DAN It is hard to understand your rac_checkStoresAvailability. And could you let me know what is button & btnRegister?

Comment: sorry for the mistakes, I've just updated my code. There's just one button in the view controller binded to the signal rac_checkEntitiesAvailability of the view-model, which is meant to check whether there are entities available and if needed try to download them; let me know if you need further details

Comment: @DAN Added some examples. And if you want to send some signals by yourself, try to alloc a RACSubject and send signals via it. [RACSignal return:] is not friendly to reader. :)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Harrison. Actually my downloadEntites method is quite similar to yours but it's in a Service Manager singleton and not in the Entity itself; regarding the MR_ methods they belong to the MagicalRecord library (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).  Details aside I'd prefer an approach similar to my code where I can leave all the business logic in the viewModel; this way the view controller can be unaware of the Entity class, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, you are right. We should put logic in the viewModel. So why not putting RACCommand in your viewModel?

Comment: We can do that, but we'd always need a RACCommand in the view controller which takes care to perform the segue or present an error message to the user